# Is this the best way to deploy a website using TFS 2012

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, tfsbuild

I want to deploy a website on check-in of code to TFS.

So I created a build definition that has MSBuild arguments (under Advanced)

/p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=MyProfileName

This publish script copies the output to the website virtual directory folder on the web server.

My question is Is this the best way to do what I am d

Comment: There is no best way. Best way is one that satisfies your business. If I would do something like this they would kill me. We have CI, and nightly, and on-demand, builds and deployments. But deploying on check-in is a no-no for us. If you are one-man shop, this is may be good for you. See where I'm going?

Comment: I got you. I guess I want to know if this was the most popular technique of doing a deployment using TFS. I have seen where people are using TFS Build workflows to do deployments

Comment: @T.S., his idea has merit but only if it deploys to an intranet location to facilitate testing.  Having it auto-deploy on successful build to allow BVT and smoke check removes a maintenance dependency for testers.